# What does "Carry the decimal to four places" on line 47 "Deduction percentage" mean in 2016 Schedule CA NR?

Tags: united-states, taxes, california

If I get 0.93342 after "Divide line 37, column E by line 37, column D", then should I put down 0.9334 or 1.000, given the "Carry the decimal to four places" instruction?

When I read "Carry the decimal to four places", I think 0.93342 * 10000 = 9334.2, which would be greater than 1.000.

Common sense tells me 0.93342 is what I should enter.

Edit: [Instructions for 2016 Schedule CA NR](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2016/16_540nrcains.pdf)

Comment: Provide a link to the form and instructions?  Are you instructed to multiply by 10,000 or are you thinking that "carry the decimal" means multiplication?

Comment: I'm thinking that "carry the decimal" means multiplication.

Comment: It doesn't, it means "preserve that many digits after the decimal when you copy (carry) the number to the next place it is used".   `0.9334` is what you should enter.  The trailing `2` is a fifth decimal, which you should not preserve (the tax office won't when it repeats your calculations, and you don't want to have mismatching numbers)

Comment: Would you mind making that last comment an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The instruction is

> [image]

There is no multiplication or moving of decimal points involved.  Perform the division (result = `0.93342`), round to the nearest `0.0001` so you are left with four digits after the decimal (result = `0.9334`) and enter `0.9334` into Line 47.

"Carry" here has the same meaning as in "carry forward" -- to copy your result to somewhere it is needed.

You shouldn't preserve extra precision (the fifth digit, `2`) because the tax office won't when it repeats your calculations, and you don't want to have mismatching numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Carry here means that you continue doing the division until four places after the decimal point.  That is to say

```
.93342
012345
```

The 4 is at the fourth place, so you go out to .9334.  This is less than 1.0000, so you write .9334.

From the [instructions](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2016/16_540nrcains.pdf):

> **Line 47 — Deduction Percentage**
>   Divide line 37, column E by line 37, column D.  Carry the decimal to four places.  This number may not be greater than 1.0000.  If the result is greater than 1.0000, enter 1.0000.